# Unable to update div text from ajax response sent via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Apologies for this question if something out there covers this. I searched and found many relevant posts which has allowed me to get to this point.

I have a form snippet with 1 input box and a button and a div for a status message:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input id="discount_code"name="discount_code" placeholder="  Enter discount code."></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="btn-validate">Validate</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="status_msg" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>
</div>
```

Then I have the following bits of javascript:

1. The bit that triggers based on the click:

   `$('#btn-validate').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       validateCode(11); // "11" is a php-provided ID variable
   });`
2. The javscript with the ajax call:

   ```
   function validateCode(eventID) {
   var codeValue = $("#discount_code").val();
   if (FieldIsEmpty(codeValue)) { // outside function that exists/works fine
       $('#status_msg').html('Enter a discount code.').fadeIn(500);
       $('#status_msg').fadeOut(2500);
       //bootbox.alert("Please enter discount code to validate.");     
   } else {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false,
           async: true,
           url: '/include/discount_validation.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
               event_id: eventID,
               discount_code: codeValue
           },
           beforeSend: function() {
               $('#status_msg').html('');
               $('#status_msg').fadeIn(0);
           },
           success: function(data) {
               $('#status_msg').html(data);
               $('#status_msg').fadeIn(0);
               //bootbox.alert(data);
           },
           error: function(data) {
               $('#status_msg').html(data);
               $('#status_msg').fadeIn(0);
               //bootbox.alert("Error validating discount code: " + JSON.stringify(discount_code));
           }
       });
   }};
   ```

And I have a PHP file that, suffice it to say, is working and producing the following `json` outputs based on the input:

```
            // do php database things...
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(!isset($percent)) {
    //echo("Invalid code: '" . $dCode ."'");
    $message = "Invalid code: '" . $dCode ."'";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message' => "$message"));
} else {
    $message = "Code: '" . $dCode . "'" . " provides a " . $percent . "% discount.";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => "$message"));
}
```

In the above, I have `bootbox.alert` lines commented out but when they are active, the box appears and the message is as I would expect it to be.

And lastly, the first condition that triggers if the input box is empty, both fires the alert (when not commented) AND changes the text of `#status_msg`.

I put the border in to verify visibility and `#status_msg` is visible but just is not set when either success or error fires.

Comment: show the json content..

Comment: So, @Hikmat's response does indeed enable the <div> to display what I intended. Thank you. Why, however, was the message being displayed via bootbox.alert without the eval(data)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set your data like this inside `ajax()`.

```
success: function(data) {
            var result = eval(data);
            $('#status_msg').html(result.message);
            $('#status_msg').fadeIn(0);
            //bootbox.alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var result = eval(data);
            $('#status_msg').html(result.message);
            $('#status_msg').fadeIn(0);
            //bootbox.alert("Error validating discount code: " + JSON.stringify(discount_code));
        }
```

AND

```
if(!isset($percent)) {
    //echo("Invalid code: '" . $dCode ."'");
    $message = "Invalid code: '" . $dCode ."'";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message' => $message));
} else {
    $message = "Code: '" . $dCode . "'" . " provides a " . $percent . "% discount.";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if you getting an object in the response
in the success add

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

If it shows the object then you are good to go else check the php file where you creating the object.

If object is recieved in the success of ajax then you need to parse the json object using   [**jQuery.parseJSON**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

*For Eg:*

```
response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Now you have a javascript object with name `response`.

Now use it

`response['status']` or `response['message']` in the success of the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

check the code
first discard : " from php code $message variable

```
if(!isset($percent)) {
    //echo("Invalid code: '" . $dCode ."'");
    $message = "Invalid code: '" . $dCode ."'";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message' => $message));
} else {
    $message = "Code: '" . $dCode . "'" . " provides a " . $percent . "% discount.";
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message));
}
```

then use the response on font end success function :

```
success: function(data) {

            $('#status_msg').html(data.message);
            $('#status_msg').fadeIn(0);

        },
```